# Функции php не разрешены в CRON

Tags: php, cron

когда запускается крон, получаю отчет

1. `PHP Warning: parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons in`
2. `Fatal error: Class 'CurlFile' not found in`

При ручном запуске все нормально. Задание добавляю так

```
php /var/www/www-root/data/www/sait.ru/sendscript/index.php
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Крон запускается под другим пользователем, соответственно смотрите какие права на директориях с скриптом. Выставьте правильные права и будет счастье.